# Some thinking of a short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

I begin to read about Module Theory. After reading Five Lemma and Snake Lemma, I have this following statement.

**Proposition 1.** *Consider the following commutative diagram:*
[image] where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are isomorphisms. If the top row is an exact sequence, then the bottom row is also exact.

*Proof.* If $f'(x)=0$ for $x\in A',$ then there exists only $y\in A$ such that $x=\alpha(y),$ and $f'(\alpha(y))=0.$ This implies $\beta(f(y))=0,$ and so $f(y)=0$ by the property of $\beta.$ Since $f$ is injective, we have $y=0,$ and so $x=0.$  Thus $f'$ is injective.

If $c'\in C',$ then there exists $c\in C$ such that $\gamma(c)=c'.$ Since $c\in C,$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $g(b)=c.$ Then $\gamma(g(b))=c',$ implies $g'(\beta(b))=c'.$ Thus $g'$ is surjective.

By the top row is an exact sequence, we have ${\rm Im}f=\ker g.$ If $y\in {\rm Im}f',$ then $y=f'(x)$ for some $x\in A'.$ Since $x\in A',$ there exists $z\in A$ such that $x=\alpha(z),$ and so $y=f'(\alpha(z))=\beta(f(z)).$ Thus $g'(y)=g'(\alpha(f(z)))=\gamma(g(f(z)))=\gamma(0)-0,$ implies $y\in\ker g'.$ Therefore ${\rm Im}f'\subseteq\ker g'.$ If $y\in\ker g',$ then $g'(y)=0.$ Then there exists $x\in B$ such that $y=\beta(x),$ and so $0=g'(\beta(x))=\gamma(g(x)).$ This implies $g(x)=0$ i.e $x\in\ker g.$ Thus $x=f(z)$ for some $z\in A,$ and so $y=\beta(f(z))=f'(\alpha(z)).$ Therefore $\ker g'\subseteq {\rm Im}f'.$

This is my proof.  Futhermore, I think about a strong result. But I can't still complete this proof. Let's see.

**Proposition 2.** *Consider the following diagram:*
[image] where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are isomorphisms. If the top row is an exact sequence, then the bottom row is also exact.

Have you ever seen this result in another books?

Comment: In proposition 2, do we not require that the diagram commutes? If we do not require that, then it is pretty darn easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: I think you cannot remove the commutativity assumption on the diagram. For example, let $A=A', B=B', C=C'$, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma = id$, top row an exact sequence and bottom consisting of zero maps.

Comment: I think this is an easy fact so many people just use it without proof.

Comment: Thank you so much @Arthur. I think that it is easy to see this but it is false.